# What if two app declare android app links with same domain

Tags: android, applinks

From the [doc of app links](https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/verify-site-associations), it's clear that it will directly go to my app if the user clicks a corresponding URL.

But what if I declare two apps in one `.well-known/assetlinks.json` and user installed both, and then click a corresponding URL?

Will android system show a panel with two apps for the user to select?

Answer (score 2):

This use case is mentioned in the Android Doc [here](https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/verify-site-associations#multi-app-same-domain). This is a valid case where multiple apps belonging to the same organization can respond to the same hostname. Another use case is where you have a full and lite version of the same app.

According to the doc, the most recent installed version in the above case would get the control directly and then in that app you can

> show a custom chooser dialog that contains the results from calling
> [queryIntentActivities()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager#queryIntentActivities(android.content.Intent,%20android.content.pm.PackageManager.ResolveInfoFlags))

given that you have necessary [package visibility](https://developer.android.com/training/package-visibility)